# Трудный текст

Tags: грамматика

Когда-то в школе мы писали текст, который считался трудным с точки зрения грамматики. По-моему, что-то из Чехова. Были слова "винегрет", "терраса" (уже не помню, как правильно). Не могли бы напомнить источник. Хотел проверить внучек. Или может предложите наиболее трудные тексты с точки зрения грамматики. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, можно взять такой вариант: *на дощатой брусчатой террасе, сидя на оттоманке вблизи можжевельника, вдова небезызвестного подьячего веснушчатая Агриппина Савична исподтишка потчевала винегретом и прочими яствами коллежского асессора Аполлона Филипповича под аккомпанемент аккордеона и виолончели.*  А вообще их превеликое множество.

Comment: Вы считаете, что Николай не в сострянии открыть ссылку в моём ответе?

Comment: Не в состОянии.

Answer (score 0):

Вот один вариант, пожалуй получше других будет.

*С камушка на камушек порхал воробышек, а на террасе, искусно задрапированной гобеленами с дефензивой кронштадтского инфантерийского батальона, под искусственным абажуром, закамуфлированным под марокканский минарет, веснушчатая свояченица вдовствующего протоиерея Агриппина Саввична потчевала коллежского асессора, околоточного надзирателя и индифферентного ловеласа Фаддея Аполлинарьевича винегретом со снетками.*

Здесь все слова или чисто словарные, или на достаточно редкие правила. Более "развернутые" варианты слишком разбавлены простыми и неинтересными случаями. Но если поискать, найдёте много.

Чехов здесь рядом не лежал. Это чисто искусственные тескты, авторство - народное (признаюсь, в том числе и моё).